# Best python module manager for windows

Tags: python, windows, module, pip, module-management

I always have to search google for some EXE or MSI to install module in python on Windows
Sometimes there are precompiled modules only for win32 but not amd64

I am debating to use ActiveState Python or install some module manager.

Could you advice the best solution. Especially if you use it yourself.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular one I know of these days is [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/), often used in conjunction with [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/) for sandboxing your development environments.

There are a number of articles on getting started with the combo of the two:

- http://guide.python-distribute.org/pip.html
- http://jontourage.com/2011/02/09/virtualenv-pip-basics/
- http://rubayeet.com/2011/03/04/getting-started-with-pipvirtualenv/

Comment: Wondering why someone minus that post? I would like to hear comments. I even put pip in tags and reviewed it as option.